# Prove the continuity of the function using $\epsilon-\delta$ definition.

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

A function $f(z)$ is defined by
$$
f(z)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
-(5+4 i) ; & z=-(1+2 i) \\
\frac{z^{2}-3 z-10 i}{z+(1+2 i)} ; & z \neq-(1+2 i)
\end{array}\right.
$$
By using $\epsilon-\delta$ definition, prove that $f$ is continuous at
$z_0=-(1+2 i)$

I got that $|f(z)-f(z_0)|=|\frac{z^2+2z-4iz+1-8i}{z+(1+2i)}|$, How to make it $<\epsilon$ ?

Comment: First off, do a round of polynomial division. The resulting expression really ought to be easier to work with.

Comment: your expression for $|f(z) - f(z_0)| $ is incorrect